# Getting the records of last 6 months in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have been working on a query to return the last 6 months, for example:

If the current month is April 2018, then the query should return the record of last 6 months ex:

- Nov 2017
- Dec 2017
- Jan 2018
- Feb 2018
- March 2018
- April 2018

My current query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  monthname(batchEndDate) AS month,
  batchDetails.bATCHiD,
  batchDetails.batchEndDate,
  COUNT(EnrollmentNumber) AS count
FROM candidate
INNER JOIN batchdetails
  ON candidate.batchId = batchDetails.batchId
WHERE (assessmentResult = "pass"
OR assessmentResult = "fail")
AND YEAR(batchEndDate) BETWEEN YEAR(batchEndDate) - 1
AND YEAR(curdate())
GROUP BY MONTH(batchEndDate)
ORDER BY month(batchEndDate);
```

Comment: I advice you to read "Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: `select distinct monthname(batchEndDate) as month,batchDetails.bATCHiD, batchDetails.batchEndDate,count(EnrollmentNumber) as count..group by month(batchEndDate) ` is invalid ANSI SQL.. MySQL allows this but you can get invalid data for non-aggregated columns which are not in the group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for MySQL's very useful date arithmetic.  In particular, the [`LAST_DAY()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) makes this straightforward.

The first day of the next month can be retrieved via:

```
 LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

So, you want all records before that....

```
  WHERE batchEndDate < LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

The first day of the month six months prior is

```
 LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 6 MONTH
```

so, you want all records after that.

```
  WHERE batchEndDate < LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    AND batchEndDate >= LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 6 MONTH
```

You want to group by month. You do that with

```
GROUP BY LAST_DAY(batchEndDate)
```

Then your query looks like this

```
select LAST_DAY(batchEndDate) as month_ending,
       monthname(LAST_DAY(batchEndDate)) as month,
       count(EnrollmentNumber) as count 
  from candidate 
 inner join batchdetails on candidate.batchId = batchDetails.batchId 
 where (assessmentResult="pass" or assessmentResult="fail") 
   and batchEndDate < LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
   and batchEndDate >= LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 6 MONTH
 GROUP BY LAST_DAY(batchEndDate)
```

Comment: I believe it should be LAST_DAY()... + INTERVAL 1 MONTH and - INTERVAL 5 MONTH. OP wants to include current month.

Comment: `select LAST_DAY(batchEndDate) as month_ending,
       monthname(batchEndDate) as month,
       count(EnrollmentNumber) as count .. GROUP BY LAST_DAY(batchEndDate)` is invalid ANSI SQL.. MySQL allows this but you can get **invalid** data for non-aggregated columns which are not in the group by,  in this case `monthname(batchEndDate)`

Comment: @RaymondNijland : batchEndDate is functionally dependent on the group by clause so it's OK.   @Salman If today is 15-Oct-2018, then `LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 1 MONTH` is 1-Dec-2018. That includes also the month *after* the current month.

Comment: i had a feeling you would bring up functional dependency.. But that only works on keys -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html ..